Action hero avenges neighbour's honour after she is raped by a gang
This movie is about a year or two old. Action violent movie. It starred either Liam Neeson, Denzel Washington, Bruce Willis, maybe even Kevin Costner.
He is ex-military (or a hitman?) and is friends with his beautiful (maybe prostitute?) neighbor. She gets raped and beaten up by this punk mafia son and wants the hero to get satisfaction.
The rest of movie is him fighting and killing the whole gang. Does this ring a bell with anyone? It's Like "The Equalizer" Or "Walk Among The Tombstones".

It sounds like Generic Revenge Action Movie. Was it maybe Ryan Gosling? He was in a couple movie that sound like this, too. You saw some of it? First half, last half? And you can't remember if the lead was black or white? There's a pretty big difference (not just skin color) between Denzel and Costner.

@DanielStowers The Punisher is about Thomas Jane avenging the death of his family.  There is also not a rape scene in that movie.

I thought "Watchmen" had a rape scene in it.  That is more of a super hero film than an action film though.

Could it be Hummingbird, released as Redemption in the US, starring Jason Statham? 
It matches some things very well, but just misses some others.
Matches

Main character is ex-military, played by a modern major action star (Jason Statham, not one of the examples listed, but similar)
It's from the last couple of years (2013)
The main character's female friend/girlfriend is forced into prostituion and is beaten and abused by some rich city slicker punk client
Much of the second half of the film is the main character fighting gangsters, seeking revenge, trying to find the guy who did it

Near misses / mismatches

Villian is not a mafia brat (but could possibly be mistaken for one). It turns out he's... 


 a "respectable" rich guy (banker, I think?) who is secretly a prostitute-murdering sadist in his spare time


The gang isn't the villain's gang (he's not a gangster), the villain is a major customer of the gang's prositute-supplying service
The girl is killed by the villain, and it all happens off-camera, we (and the hero) hear about it second-hand. This means she can't tell the hero that she "wants satisfaction" - though there is another female character who throughout the film encourages him to do what he needs to do to find peace/satisfaction - it's possible these wires got crossed.
There are several memorable details I'd have expected the asker to remember (e.g. the ex-military hero is homeless when the movie starts, there's a particularly memorable shocking scene towards the end, there's a big sub-plot with a Christian soup kitchen lady, etc)


Not sure about the title. but according to your info about the movie's age, it's probably The November Man.



